# Windows 10 Update build version

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1703

I upgraded my laptop to Windows 10 Anniversary update which is "Build 14392 (Version 1607)" and now there is a new update the "Creators Update - Build 15063" and I want to update it with ISO. Can I directly install the "Build 15603" with cleaning or install cleaning it? I'm asking about it here because I'm afraid to brick my PC.

Comment: If you do have an image with that version, yes. But how would it be different from just using the Windows update?

Answer (score 0):

Each of the updates for Windows 10 so far can either be:

**In-place**

Upgrades over an existing installation, keeping all applications and documents and other files safe.

or **Clean**

A fresh installation either from an ISO or by choosing the correct option during the installation from the various installers Microsoft offers which removes all previous data and software on the affected partitions of the hard drive it is installed to.